# Start a process using C# System.Diagnostics.Process in a virtual desktop

Tags: c#, windows-10

I am writing a `C#` program where I need to start several times an external program. I am using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` to start the external program.
Because this takes a long time I would like to run all of that in a separate Windows10 virtual `desktop#2` and do other stuff in virtual `desktop#1`. But even if I start my program in `desktop#2` and I switch to `desktop#1` the called external annoying program pops up each time in `desktop#1`, where I am doing other stuff.
I cannot see anything in the `C#` docs how to do this. Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot do it directly through C# as far as i know. But you can still do it through the Process class. Instead of starting your program directly, start/execute a utility that will launch the desired program on a specified desktop. Such a utility would be for example VDesk. More information and further links here: https://superuser.com/questions/970193/how-can-i-force-a-program-to-open-in-a-specific-desktop (I personally have no experience with VDesk; my comment here is based on the linked SuperUser question&answer)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but not for my needs. I have to wait for the started process (`Metatrader4`) to end, to get some data before starting it again. In this case `process.WaitForExit();` does not work, because it applies to `vdesk` and not to `Metatrader4`.

Comment: Well, VDesk is open-source. And, taking a cursory glance at its source code, luckily it seems to be completely (or at least mostly) written in C# (with a healthy dose of P/Invoke or COM interfacing, i presume). You might want to get the VDesk source and adapt it to your needs. Since VDesk is written in C#, you could even go as far as integrating the VDesk logic into your own project, assuming VDesks license is not being a roadblock...

Comment: Good idea. Thank you for the suggestion...